# Enabling AMDGPU

Tags: drivers, 16.04, kernel, radeon

I have an R9 390 and I have just compiled a custom kernel with "Enable amdgpu support for CIK parts" set to "yes".  I am also booting with the custom kernel boot parameter amdgpu.exp_hw_support=1

I'm aware that support for this card is experimental and could break my system.  After rebooting, the Kernel drive in use is still radeon.  I'm not sure how to proceed from here after much Google-Fu.

Comment: May be this would help : https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/AMDGPU Try tp add or edit your xorg.conf settings from radeon to amdgpu. If it doesnt work, try to blacklist radeon module.

Answer (score 1):

I gave up on the custom kernel.  I scrapped MATE Ubuntu and did a fresh install of Kubuntu 16.04.1 (Apparently KDE Plays nicer with AMDGPU-PRO).  After the fresh installation, I installed the official AMDGPU-PRO 16.30 drivers using only the instructions on the website.

I rebooted and confirmed that the new drivers were installed.  I ran Unigine Valley benchmark using the Radeon and the AMDGPU-PRO on my R9 390.  The results were extraordinary:

Radeon - 15.0 Avg FPS - 627 Score

AMDGPU-PRO - 60.2 Avg FPS - 2517 Score (2551 in Win10)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this: [oibaf open source driver](https://launchpad.net/~oibaf/+archive/ubuntu/graphics-drivers)

It works on Ubuntu GNOME, for newer and old radeon cards.